# Remove displays from xrandr

Tags: xrandr, external-monitor

How to remove displays (external screens connected to XPS 9350) from xrandr. Currently my xrandr -q looks like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1800, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.98*+  47.99  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

How to remove DP1,..., VIRTUAL1. I know that this are displays I connected. However, all of them where (probably) just projectors used on some conferences. Removing .config/monitors.xml does not help.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not representing monitors or other display devices that previously were connected.

They represent output connections.

- eDP1: DisplayPort for laptop monitor
- DP1,DP2: two DisplayPorts
- HDMI1,HDMI2: two HDMI ports
- VIRTUAL1: Virtual port

Depending on driver features, you may able to disable some using Xorg custom settings.